# smarty fetch string replace

Tags: php, smarty

When using $smarty->fetch, it pulls the template into a variable. Is there way to do pre-parsed string manipulation on that variable?

Example:

PHP:

```
$variable = $smarty->fetch('template.tpl');
$variable = str_replace("{include file='../another_dir", "{include file='", $variable);
```

template.tpl

```
{include file='incl.tpl'}
```

Ideal result would be to have the template become:

```
{include file='../another_dir/incl.tpl'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must edit template first. Then you can use fetch.

Something like this:

```
$template = file_get_contents('template.tpl');
$template = str_replace("{include file='../another_dir", "{include file='", $template);
$variable = $smarty->fetch('string:' . $template);
```

Smarty [String Template Resources](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.string.tpl).